# Replace existing code

Tags: awk

I was wondering if someone could help me here. I want to convert some menu items into Bootstrap conventions; unfortunately there are more than 1000 lines of code and I'd like to achieve it automagically instead of editing the whole file manually. Do you think it is possible?

The original code looks like:

```
<span class="header"><img src="images/icons/anicon.png" class="absmiddle" width="16" height="16" /> {$_thetitle}</span>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="anurl.php"><img src="images/icons/todolist.png" class="absmiddle" width="16" height="16" /> {$_sometextinhere}</a></li>
        <li><a href="anurl.php?action=anaction"><img src="images/icons/anicon.png" class="absmiddle" width="16" height="16" /> {$_sometextinhere}</a></li>
        <li><a href="anurl.php"><img src="images/icons/domains.png" class="absmiddle" width="16" height="16" /> {$_sometextinhere}</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onClick="showDialog('geninvoices');return false"><img src="images/icons/someicon.png" class="absmiddle" width="16" height="16" /> {$_sometextinhere}</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onClick="showDialog('cccapture');return false"><img src="images/icons/anothericon.png" class="absmiddle" width="16" height="16" /> {$_sometextinhere}</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And I need to convert that into:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>&nbsp; {$_thetitle}
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="anurl.php" class="list-group-item">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; {$_sometextinhere}
    </a>
    <a href="anurl.php" class="list-group-item">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; {$_sometextinhere}
    </a>
    <a href="anurl.php?action=anaction" class="list-group-item">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; {$_sometextinhere}
    </a>
    <a href="#" onClick="showDialog('cccapture');return false" class="list-group-item">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; {$_sometextinhere}
    </a>
    <a href="#" onClick="showDialog('cccapture');return false" class="list-group-item">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; {$_sometextinhere}
    </a>
</div>
```

The font-awesome icon can be the same for all of them, I can change them manually later, but I certainly need to get rid of the  tags, convert the ul tags, and add the others... Do you believe it is possible to make such transformation without much manual intervention?

Thanks for your advise.
Regards

Comment: There is literally no common elements between these two code snippets, so I think you would spend more time writing rules to feed into a parsing engine than it would take to rewrite the content.

Comment: And manipulating DOM is not very "cheap" when you're talking about hundreds of elements.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you need to do the replace dynamically (which would justify the use of JS) or statically (wherefore a better tool should be used, e.g. `awk`)? [What have you tried?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Whenever I have something like this I'll often put the raw html into browser and write some jQuery script to modify it then save the modifed html

Comment: Hi @FélixSaparelli, by this time I haven't tried anything, I'm sorry. I thought of Javascript as I've performed other replacements in the past, but never on this scale. Thanks for your recommendation; I'll reformulate the tag.

Comment: Well... One day I will finish :P hahaha...

Comment: @DanielFelipe Maybe use a text editor that support multi cursors?

Comment: @dev-null excellent!, just found out how with Sublime text... Well, I will have to do it manually but I believe that's simply the best option. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielFelipe I'm glad that i could help, if you feel you gotten an answer to your question please accept it or close the answer all together - the later is mostly for questions that are not constructive for other people. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a text editor that supports multi cursors, for instance Sublime Text. You can press select the text and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> (Mac: <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>) to select the next occasion(s) of that text. When you are done simply press <kbd>esc</kbd>:

[image: Multi cursor Sublime Text Demo]

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading you correctly...  The following will do what you want and also will print lines in file that do not match...

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { inmenu = 0 }
/<span class="header">/ {
        print "<div class=\"panel panel-default\">"
        print "<div class=\"panel-heading\">"
        print "    <h3 class=\"panel-title\">"
        print "            <i class=\"fa fa-arrow-left\"></i>&nbsp; " sometextinhere($0)
        print "    </h3>"
        print "</div>"
        next
}
/<ul class="menu">/ {
        inmenu = 1
        print "<div class=\"list-group\">"
        next
}
inmenu && /href="anurl\.php"><img src="images\/icons\/todolist\.png"/ {
        print "    <a href=\"anurl.php\" class=\"list-group-item\">"
        print "        <i class=\"fa fa-arrow-left fa-fw\"></i>&nbsp; " sometextinhere($0)
        print "    </a>"
        next
}
inmenu && /href="anurl\.php\?action/ {
        print "    <a href=\"anurl.php\" class=\"list-group-item\">"
        print "        <i class=\"fa fa-arrow-left fa-fw\"></i>&nbsp; " sometextinhere($0)
        print "    </a>"
        next
}
inmenu && /href="anurl\.php\?action/ {
        print "    <a href=\"anurl.php\" class=\"list-group-item\">"
        print "        <i class=\"fa fa-arrow-left fa-fw\"></i>&nbsp; " sometextinhere($0)
        print "    </a>"
        next
}
inmenu && /href="anurl\.php"><img\ src="images\/icons\/domains\.png"/ {
        print "    <a href=\"anurl.php?action=anaction\" class=\"list-group-item\">"
        print "        <i class=\"fa fa-arrow-left fa-fw\"></i>&nbsp; " sometextinhere($0)
        print "    </a>"
        next
}
inmenu && /href="#" onClick="showDialog\('(geninvoices|cccapture)'\)/ {
        print "    <a href=\"#\" onClick=\"showDialog('cccapture');return false\" class=\"list-group-item\">"
        print "        <i class=\"fa fa-arrow-left fa-fw\"></i>&nbsp; " sometextinhere($0)
        print "    </a>"
        next
}
inmenu && /<\/ul>/ {
        print "</div>"
        inmenu = 0
        next
}
{ print; next }

function sometextinhere(line,    r) {
        r = line
    sub(/.* class="absmiddle" width="16" height="16" \/> /, "", r)
        sub(/\<\/a\>\<\/li\>[ \t]*$/, "", r)
        return r
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Michael for your time spent on this; I found multi-cursors more useful for this specific task. Unfortunately I can't guarantee that the whole document looks the same and uses the same conventions, so I would certainly have had to add more rules. Yet thank you for your time, I highly appreciate it!

Comment: I'll still finish it up...  This is just an example of to do sth like what you want in AWK... If a general solution is needed, what I do typically is use some kind of external template -- like what you do with a mail merge kind of thing... but one-offs like this are no big deal